# I cannot run my sapper application after running npm run dev command in the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, single-page-application, sapper

When I run the `npm run dev` command in the terminal, I have the following error:
Please what do you think can be the problem? I have tried deleting the node module folder and reinstalling dependencies over but it does not seem to work for me.
Thank you

````js
> TODO@0.0.1 dev D:\PROJECTS\Svelte && Sapper\my-app
> sapper dev

'Sapper\my-app\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\PROJECTS\sapper\sapper'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! TODO@0.0.1 dev: `sapper dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the TODO@0.0.1 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Stanley\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-10T23_50_59_186Z-debug.log```
````

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the dependencies first by running npm install

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not inside the directory of your project. You should be inside D:/PROJECTS/Svelte/[Project Name], and then call `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when using unstable software such as NPM or sapper and you run into problems, try to reset your environment to defaults - in this case, I believe `npm cache clean --force` would help.